# PHP Rename error : The system cannot find the path specified. (code: 3)

Tags: php, codeigniter

I want to move an excel file from one folder to another, I  have used the following line of code

```
 $approve_employee_id = $this->input->post('approve_employee_id');
        $approve_month_id = $this->input->post('approve_month_name');
        $approve_year_name = $this->input->post('approve_year_name');
        $approve_employee_username = $this->input->post('approve_employee_username');
        $folder_name = $approve_month_id.$approve_year_name;
        rename(".files/".$folder_name."/un_approved/".$approve_employee_username, ".files/".$folder_name."/approved/".$approve_employee_username);
```

I keep on getting the  following error from the  system :

```
A PHP Error was encountered

Severity: Warning

Message: rename(.files/January2013/un_approved/HS0103,.files/January2013/approved/HS0103): The system cannot find the path specified. (code: 3)

Filename: controllers/time_sheet.php

Line Number: 279
```

My folder tree is as follows : 
`C:\xampp\htdocs\timesheet\files\January2013\approved` for approved and `C:\xampp\htdocs\timesheet\files\January2013\un_approved` for un approved

Please advise on the  best way to implement this ?

Comment: `The system cannot find the path specified.` What do you not understand about the error message?

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you should use "`./files`", instead of "`.files`" ...?

However, I'd suggest to decouple the location of your data files from the location of your php script... So, I should do:

```
...
$basedir = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . "/timesheet/files/$folder_name";
rename("$basedir/un_approved/$approve_employee_username", "$basedir/approved/$approve_employee_username);
```

This approach makes your life easier when you should deploy your code do different web servers, for example...

Answer (score 0):

use `__DIR__`.'./../yourfolder/'
I tried and it works

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -1):

I just stick to full path as it makes it much more easy to understand ...

for example

```
dirname(__FILE__).'/files/etc/etc/path.yourfile';
```

you can go up the tree by

```
dirname(dirname(__FILE__)).'/files/etc/etc/path.yourfile'; and so on
```

You can try this ...

```
$files_folder = dirname(__FILE__); //or go up as required.
```

Then

```
 rename($files_folder."/".$folder_name."/un_approved/".$approve_employee_username, $files_folder."/".$folder_name."/approved/".$approve_employee_username);
```